# VBA use Collection for entire workbook

Tags: excel, vba, function, scope, global-variables

I need to use Collection variable in Global scope. But if i declare collection as public I can use it only in module sheet or worksheet. I need to declare it for entire workbook scope to use it in workbook functions, worksheet functions and module functions.

ThisWorkbook

```
Public foo As New Collection
```

Worksheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
row= Target.Row
column= Target.Column
        If Cells(row, 2).Value = "" Then
        Exit Sub
        Else
                If Cells(row, 1).Value = "" Then

                    foo.Add row- 5

                    Cells(row, 1).Value = "X"
                    Cells(row, 2).Select
                    Cells(row, 14).Value = True
                Else

                    foo.Remove row- 5

                    Cells(row, 1).Value = ""
                    Cells(row, 2).Select
                    Cells(row, 14) = False
                End If
        End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Module:

```
Sub col()
MsgBox foo.Count
End Sub
```

Comment: Declare it in a standard module.

Comment: Could you explan me what "standard module" means?

Comment: VBA uses sheet, standard, form and class modules. Only the first one type is associated to an existing worksheet, or to the whole workbook  (`ThisWorkbook`). The other three types must be inserted. Being in VBE, right click on 'Microsoft Excel Objects' -> 'Insert' and choose 'Module'. This one is a standard module type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Standard Module:

```
Private m_collection As Collection

Public Property Get TheCollection() As Collection
    If m_collection Is Nothing Then Set m_collection = New Collection
    Set TheCollection = m_collection 
End Property
```

---

Then you can call it from anywhere in your code.

```
ModuleName.TheCollection.Add("whatever")
```